# Why does jruby complain about valid java_opts

Tags: java, jruby, jrubyonrails, java-opts

I have set my java min/max heap size to be the same as outlined in the [Sun Docs](http://java.sun.com/docs/hotspot/gc5.0/gc_tuning_5.html#0.0.0.%20Total%20Heap%7Coutline) for precise heap sizing using the following:

```
-Xms768m -Xmx768m
```

This works fine when I start tomcat, but if I run `jruby` from the command line it complains saying:

> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>   Incompatible minimum and maximum heap sizes specified

I read in the [jruby docs](http://kenai.com/projects/jruby/pages/PerformanceTuning) about some -J-X params but it seems silly that I would need to explicitly override my normal jvm settings.

The problem arises when I do a deploy.  I try running `jruby -S rake db:migrate` on my server and it complains.

Is it true that I need to explicitly override my JVM settings when running jruby?  It seems as though ANY Xms/Xmx values cause jruby to complain.

**Update**
So it seems that *some* settings do in fact work.  For instance all of these work:

```
Xmx256m Xms256m
Xmx512m Xms256m
Xmx512m Xms500m
```

But these don't:

```
Xmx512m Xms512m
Xmx512m Xms501m
Xmx768m Xms512m
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a limitation of JRuby's shell launcher. The good news that the native JRuby launcher handles that properly, you could install it via:

```
jruby -S gem install jruby-launcher
```

P.S. In case you see such problems, feel free to file bugs against JRuby: http://bugs.jruby.org

Comment: Actually I did:  Forgot to update here, thx for the reminder:
http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-4702

Does installing jruby-launcher overwrite the original jruby command? or does it provide another executable?

Comment: When you install the native JRuby launcher (on *nix), it overwrites 'jruby' file, but the old shell-based launcher is available via jruby.sh.